# RDS Server 2016 Disable Easy Print on Epson TM (POS receipt printer)

Tags: windows-server-2016, remote-desktop-services, drivers, rds, printer

Currently have RDS setup on Win Server 2016 it is using the "Easy Print Driver" for all locally connected (redirected) Epson TM t20-ii printers (about 10 POS receipt paper stations).

I have installed the most recent driver on clients + RDS server Ver.5.09E (claims to include support for Server 2016 64-bit + Client OS (Win 10 64-bit)).

I've used GPO to disable "use easy print first" on computer/user policies.

I've attempted to edit the advanced printer settings, but the whole section is grayed out, won't let you change driver.

The printer "works" if you let it print 8.5x11, but that doesn't look so good on 80mm rolls.

I had this working on an RDS Win Server 2012, so I know it should be possible. I'm hoping there is a simple, do this option, or change xyz setting.

Under Print Server Properties on RDS server it shows installed driver: EPSON TM-T20II Receipt5, x64, Type 3 - User Mode